# If use async/await, it transpiles code above my "imports" and makes my func undefined

Tags: babeljs

I currently have this code:

```
// Imports
const {utils: Cu, Constructor: CC} = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript('chrome://trigger/content/webextension/scripts/3rd/polyfill.min.js');

function install() {}
function uninstall() {}
function shutdown() {}
function startup() { // this gets automatically called by the environment i am designing for
   Services.prompt.alert(Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser'), 'title', 'body');
}

async function doAsync() {
    return await new Promise(() => setTimeout(()=>resolve('done'), 5000));
}
```

However after compiling with babel with this `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "es2017"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
    "ignore": [
      "3rd/**/*",
    ]
}
```

It moves my `doAsync` function to the top. Before the imports. Which is a problem. Because the import needs to happen right away. As `startup` gets called right away.

The compiled code becomes this:

```
'use strict';

var doAsync = function () {
   var _ref = _asyncToGenerator(regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
      return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
         while (1) {
            switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
               case 0:
                  _context.next = 2;
                  return new Promise(function () {
                     return setTimeout(function () {
                        return resolve('done');
                     }, 5000);
                  });

               case 2:
                  return _context.abrupt('return', _context.sent);

               case 3:
               case 'end':
                  return _context.stop();
            }
         }
      }, _callee, this);
   }));

   return function doAsync() {
      return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
   };
}();

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments); return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { function step(key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) { step("next", value); }, function (err) { step("throw", err); }); } } return step("next"); }); }; }

// Imports
var _Components = Components,
    Cu = _Components.utils,
    CC = _Components.Constructor;

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript('chrome://trigger/content/webextension/scripts/3rd/polyfill.min.js');

function install() {}
function uninstall() {}
function shutdown() {}
function startup() {
   // this gets automatically called by the environment i am designing for       Services.prompt.alert(Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser'), 'title', 'body');
}
```

Is there anyway so that if I use `async`/`await` that it doesn't move stuff to above my imports? If my imports at the top of the file, it fails to run. Because the imports brings in the `polyfill.min.js`

Comment: It's a function declaration, so it is hoisted. You could do `var doAsync = async function (){}`, would that be acceptable?

Comment: Oh very interesting thanks @loganfsmyth ! I have a ton of these, it would be awesome if there was another way, but if that's the only way I'll do it. Thanks for this reply!

Comment: Normally my recommendation would be to load the polyfill up front before executing any of the code output by Babel. Like you could have a dummy file that loads the polyfill, and then once that is done, loads your Babel-processed files.

Comment: Thanks @loganfsmyth ! That fixes things very well!